# how can I connect (configure) dsl modem to dhcp server in packet tracer

Tags: vlan

How can I assign DHCP IP to the DSL modem

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

A (pure) DSL modem is a bridge device working on layer 2 - it's got no IP address that would rely on DHCP.